# Samsung Gear2 Native Development

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

It looks like that Tizen supports both HTML5 and native development. However, is it possible to develop Gear2 apps natively? If yes, where possible to find any samples for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes to make apps natively, visit

http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-gear

Download their Tizen IDE, after which they have bundled with it a lot of NATIVE apps developed on Tizen, including Camera App, etc. along with all the source code.

It also comes along with emulator for easy testing/debugging.

Source: My job currently is developing Samsung Gear 2 Applications.

[image: Once you have everything setup, it should look like this.]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for reply. I'll test it as soon I solve issues with opening Tizen IDE.

Comment: @Chrles if not a big secret what are you doing for gear2? It's completely off topic but I'm really curios about Gear2 development.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that Camera app and other example apps are developed with JavaScript and CSS. There's no native development in C++ as opposed to pure Tizen OS development. Please prove me if I wrong.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to develop pure native apps for Gear2. 
similar thread is already answered in Tizen forum, check the below link:
https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/capturing-audio-web-app?langredirect=1

Comment: Tizen was created to be HTML CSS JS driven. The Libraries provided by samsung to support gear2 all writen in the above langauges.

Comment: So the apps you see in your tizen are as Native as you can get. Other options include using Cordova etc as a layer on top of GEAR2 dev.

Comment: And sorry, I'm not allowed to talk about what im doing for work :P

Answer (score 0):

No and Yes,

If you mean Native by non interpreted language like javascript , there is none ... AFAIK the only open API are using javascript at least on SDK 2.3.1_RC7 (tizen 2.3.1) ...

The system is GNU/Linux based so of course it could run all kind of technology (Qt?) but this is not the supported way (think about publishing into tizen store) ...